# Illegal member initialization in C++

Tags: c++

```
class ZooAnimal {
public:
    virtual void draw();
    int resolveType() {return myType;}
protected:
    int myType;
};

class Bear : public ZooAnimal {
public:
    Bear (const char *name) : myName(name), myType(1){}
    void draw(){ };
private:
    std::string myName;
};

void main()
{
   
}
```

When I am compiling above code I am geeting following error

> error C2614: 'Bear' : illegal member initialization: 'myType' is not a base or member

Why am I getting the above error, as we can access protected member from the derived class?

Comment: See this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290733/initialize-parents-protected-members-with-initialization-list-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error C2614: 'ChildClass' : illegal member initialization: 'var1' is not a base or member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138424/error-c2614-childclass-illegal-member-initialization-var1-is-not-a-base)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't initialize base class member in derived class initializer lists.

You'll need to provide a constructor to the base class:

```
class ZooAnimal {
public:

    ZooAnimal(int type) : myType(type) {}

    virtual void draw();
    int resolveType() {return myType;}
    protected:
    int myType;
};
```

and call it from the derived class:

```
class Bear : public ZooAnimal {
public:
                            //here//
Bear (const char *name) : ZooAnimal(1), myName(name) {}

void draw(){ };
private:
    std::string myName;
};
```

Comment: How can we initialize base class member in derived class?

Comment: @venkysmarty You can also write `myType = 1;` in the body of the derived constructor.